# awscli query ec2 describe-instances

Tags: amazon-ec2

how can I use --query and get only few fields

1.) aws ec2 describe-instances --output json --region us-east-1
2.) aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,State.Name,InstanceType,PrivateIpAddress,PublicIpAddress]' --output json --region us-east-1

The command 1 shows all values but the command 2 should null values. What went wrong in command 2

Answer (score 1):

Corrected the command -

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query  'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,State.Name,InstanceType,PrivateIpAddress,PublicIpAddress]'
```

You missed the * Due to which you got null values.